# Should I capitalize "Billion" in a bulleted list?

Tags: capitalization, numbers

I have list of values in a report used to highlight demographic information.  For dollar values, should I capitalize the word "Billion", or leave it lower case?

Here's a sample:

> **Appraised Value: $4.8 Billion**
>
> - Agriculture $0.1 Billion
> - Residential $3.3 Billion
> - Commercial $1.1 Billion
> - Other $0.3 Billion

Comment: In general text, I would use lower case.  In a title, I would use capital.  Which do you consider this to be?

Comment: @GEdgar, your comment was helpful in getting me to think through what I was trying to accomplish.  If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general text, I would use lower case. In a title, I would use capital. Which do you consider this to be?

Comment: Thanks for the in-sight.  Since these highlights are sentence fragments to begin with, I didn't think traditional grammar would have a direct answer.  I do like framing them in terms of general grammar "types", and using that as a guide.  In the end, they'll be more like general text in a bulleted list, and I'm going to leave them lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you put it in title case? What makes the word *billion* a proper noun? 
Those are rhetorical questions. Your bullets should look like this:

Agriculture: $0.1 billion

Residential: $3.3 billion

Commercial:  $1.1 billion

Other:       $0.3 billion

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This answer would be a lot more useful if there was less rhetoric, and more references.